# Amchart : changing color of MapChart bug

Tags: dictionary, colors, amcharts

I have a MapChart of the world with no color (grey by default for countries and white for the oceans):

[image]

My code:

```
var container = am4core.create("concatChart", am4core.Container);
container.width = am4core.percent(100);
container.height = am4core.percent(100);

this.mapChart = container.createChild(am4maps.MapChart);
this.mapChart.geodata = am4geodata_continentsHigh;
this.mapChart.projection = new am4maps.projections.Miller();

var polygonSeries = this.mapChart.series.push(new am4maps.MapPolygonSeries());
polygonSeries.useGeodata = true;
```

I added some colors by adding these lines to my code :

```
this.mapChart.backgroundSeries.mapPolygons.template.polygon.fill = am4core.color("#91c2dc");
this.mapChart.backgroundSeries.mapPolygons.template.polygon.fillOpacity = 1;

polygonSeries.mapPolygons.template.fill = am4core.color("#FFFFFF");
polygonSeries.mapPolygons.template.strokeOpacity = 0;
```

but it is actually bugged, it seems like the world map is cut:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/am-charts-emkfjj?file=src/app/app.component.ts

I added more information in the code.